# 仮想環境のゲストOS上で Cドライブに書き込みできなくなる

Tags: windows, vmware

Windows Server 2012 R2のIIS上で動作しているアプリ（ASP.NET）で、
「System.IO.IOException: ディスクに十分な空き領域がありません。」
が発生するようになってしまいました。
テキストファイルにログを出力しようとしたときに発生していますが、確認したところ、このアプリに限らずCドライブへの書き込みができなくなっていることがわかりました。

**状況**
・WindowsはVMware上で動作しています。
・Cドライブには35GB程の空きがあります。
・同じディスクにあるEドライブには書き込みができます。
・Cドライブも読み取りはできます。Eドライブや別のサーバーにあるフォルダへファイルをコピーすることも可能でした。
・Cドライブ内のフォルダに対して空のフォルダや空のテキストファイルを作成しようとした場合でも、「十分な空き領域がありません」と表示されて失敗します。
・ファイルを削除しようとする場合、エクスプローラーの表示上は一旦消えますが、実際は削除できておらずF5で更新するとまたファイルが表示されるようになります。
コマンドプロンプトからのdelやrmdirでも削除はできません。
・Windowsを再起動しても解消しませんでした。
・イベントビューアを確認しても上記のエラーが最初に発生した時間帯にはログがありませんでした。
ただ、再起動後はイベントビューアにログが増えていくようになりました。
この機能に関してはCドライブに書き込みができるようになったようです。
・バックアップから数日前の状態に戻したところ復旧しましたが、同じくらいの日にちが経ったところで再発しました。

このような状況を経験されたことがある方はいらっしゃらないでしょうか？
他に確認すべき箇所の心当たりなど、情報をいただけるとありがたいです。

※3/20追記
回答いただいた皆様ありがとうございます。
新しく仮想環境を作り直す方向で進んでいます。
・シン プロビジョニングになっていました。
・ホスト側の容量は足りていました。
・この状態になってもEドライブには書き込みや削除ができます。

Comment: VMware（仮想環境）を使われているようですが、システムの構成をもう少し説明してください。「Windows Server 2012 R2のIIS上で動作しているアプリ」というのはホスト(Windows Server 2012がインストールされたマシン）で稼働しているのですよね？　では、「WindowsはVMware上で動作しています」のWindowsは、どのように使われているのでしょうか。　Cドライブは、ホストにも、仮想環境にも存在します（ホストのCドライブの一部を、仮想環境のCドライブとして見せています）。質問に書かれている『Cドライブ』は、それぞれ、どのマシン（ホスト、仮想環境(いくつ作られているのでしょう））のCドライブの事ですか？

Comment: Windows 2012R2、IIS、ASP.NETのアプリとも動作しているのは仮想環境側です。Cドライブに書き込みができない件も含め、「○状況」の後に記載した内容は全て仮想環境側のことです。私がいまログインできるのも仮想環境上のWindowsのほうだけなので、申し訳ないですがVMwareで他にいくつ仮想環境が動作しているかなどは確認できていません。

Comment: ログインできるのが仮想環境上のWindowsのほうだけということなので、仮想環境の管理者が別途おられるのだと思います。まずは仮想環境の管理者に状況を説明してみてはいかがでしょうか？(そもそもCドライブに書き込みできない環境の可能性もありますし。)

Comment: 管理者もこの状況は承知しています。特に設定を変えられたというわけでもなく急に書き込みができなくなってしまったという状況です。「System.IO.IOException: ディスクに十分な空き領域がありません。」が発生した処理も、その直前まではファイルに追記ができていました。

Answer (score -1):

ホストのCドライブの容量に余裕があるのであれば、[仮想ゲスト環境のドライブ容量を拡張する方法](https://www.projectgroup.info/tips/VMware/comm_0029.html)が使えるかもしれません。
ホストの管理者が操作する必要がありますが。

Answer (score -1):

仮想ディスクの割り当て方法によっては作成時に最大サイズを埋めるのではなく、使用するにつれてディスクを(最大サイズまで)拡張してく方法があります。

[仮想ディスクのプロビジョニング ポリシーについて (シン プロビジョニング)](https://docs.vmware.com/jp/VMware-vSphere/6.5/com.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc/GUID-4C0F4D73-82F2-4B81-8AA7-1DD752A8A5AC.html)

その他にも、仮想マシンに割り当てたメモリサイズと同じ容量のメモリスワップファイル(*.vmem)が必要となったり、仮想マシンのスナップショット等で**ホストOS側**のディスク容量に問題が出ている可能性があります。

[Solved: 仮想ディスク******.vmdkのための空き容量がありません。](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/600715)

Answer (score -1):

VMWareの「中の」OSが認識している仮想ディスクの割当先となっている「物理ディスク」が
枯渇してるんじゃないですかね。
どちらにしても、仮想サーバ（ホスト）の管理者に確認するのがよいかと思います。